# AsPlainText security

Tags: security, powershell, powershell-3.0, plaintext, powershell-cmdlet

Trying to clarify the `-AsPlainText` parameter in the [ConvertTo-SecureString](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849818.aspx) cmdlet:

> -AsPlainText
>
> Specifies a plain text string to convert to a secure string. The
>   secure string cmdlets help protect confidential text. The text is
>   encrypted for privacy and is deleted from computer memory after it is
>   used. **If you use this parameter to provide plain text as input, the
>   system cannot protect that input in this manner**. To use this
>   parameter, you must also specify the Force parameter.

Can anyone explain what are the security implications implied by the bolded statement above? Is it safe to encrypt the contents of the string to a file by using this parameter?

Answer (score 4):

The point of a SecureString is to keep a string encrypted in memory. The purpose of `ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText` is to convert an already plaintext password to a secure one. The problem with this though, is that *you already have a plaintext string in memory*, which doesn't really give you much protection.

`ConvertTo-SecureString` prefers taking already encrypted string and key and converting them into secure strings, so the plaintext value is never stored in memory anywhere. Alternatively you can also use other methods to create a SecureString, such as `Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let's say that I encrypt some files under a user account on Server A, store those files on Server B and eventually decrypt those files, again, under the same user on Server A? Are those encrypted files safe on Server B?